# To prove existence of a sequence $c_n$ such that $f(c_i)=f(c_j),\forall i,j \in \Bbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$f$ is continuous function and  $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$ with infinite intersection which is non empty.Then  there exist sequence $c_n$ such that $f(c_i)=f(c_j)$ for every $i,j \in N$

I am not able to start as I was thinking to use compactness property but not able to write. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: As long as you can write the dollar sign, backslash and the underscore, you can write something like this in mathjax.

Comment: @SRJ Please check my editing.

Comment: Sorry Sir but it is not working in title section

Comment: Of course, one must also write things correctly and know basic latex commands by heart. It might be better to just roll back to what user RobertZ had done. I think the phone app has trouble in rendering latex in titles.

Comment: Some clarifications are needed: (1) What does $I_n$ have to do with the problem? (2) Why can't we just choose $c_1=c_2=c_3...$ to trivialize the problem? (3) Where does the compactness property appear in the problem?